# Linked List after iteration going to last node in display

Tags: java

After printing `firstnode` address it prints `last node` address so if I want to display my 
`Linked List` so what should I do?

Please give efficient solution

```
public class LLink {
    public Link first, last, tmp;

    public void add(int data) {
        Link newLink = new Link(data);
        if (first == null) {
            first = newLink;
            System.out.println(first.data);
            System.out.println(newLink);
        } else {
            first.next = newLink;
            // first=newLink;
            System.out.println(newLink.data);
            // newLink = newLink.next;
            // newLink.next=newLink;
            last = newLink;

        }
        // newLink.next=first;//it copies the address of old first
        // last=newLink;
        System.out.println("end");
        System.out.println(last);
    }

    public void delete() {
        Link tmp = first;
        first = first.next;
        System.out.println(first.data);

    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("display");
        Link e = first;
        while (e != null) {
            System.out.println(e.data);
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("first-next" + first.next);
            System.out.println(e.next);
            e = e.next;
        }

    }

    class Link {
        public int data;
        public Link next;

        public Link(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: show us some input and output. How are you running the code?

Comment: Now it has been working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your add function, not your display function.

```
public void add(int data) {
    Link newLink = new Link(data);
    if (first == null) {
        first = newLink;
        System.out.println(first.data);
        System.out.println(newLink);
    } else {
        first.next = newLink; // <-- This is wrong
        // first=newLink;
        System.out.println(newLink.data);
        // newLink = newLink.next;
        // newLink.next=newLink;
        last = newLink;

    }
    // newLink.next=first;//it copies the address of old first
    // last=newLink;
    System.out.println("end");
    System.out.println(last);
}
```

When adding to the linked list, you should add to the last node, not change the next pointer from the first node.  You've effectively made a two-node list that changes the last node every time you add a node.

Instead you should have something like:

```
public void add(int data) {
    Link newLink = new Link(data);
    if (first == null) {
        first = last = newLink;
    } else {
        last.next = newLink; // First set the next pointer of the last node to the new node
        last = newLink; // Once the pointer is set, now set last node properly
    }
}
```